# Showing every knot has a regular projection using differential topology

Tags: differential-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Can we use differential topology to prove that every smooth knot has a regular projection?

Here is some background:

Let $\gamma : S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth unit-speed imbedding.  For $v \in S^2$ we say that the projection, $\pi _v$, from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the plane orthogonal to $v$ is a *regular projection of $\gamma$* if the curve $\gamma _v := \pi _v\circ \gamma$ has the following properties:

1. $\gamma _v$ is an immersion
2. There exists a finite set  $I := \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_k, b_1, b_2,... b_k\} \subset S^1$ such that $\gamma _v |_{S^1-I}$ is injective, and $\gamma _v (a_i) = \gamma _v (b_i)$ are distinct points such that for each $i$, $\gamma _v'(a_i)$ and $\gamma _v' (b_i)$ are linearlly independent.

Now fix a particular $\gamma$. To me, the task of proving the existence of a regular projection seems like a job for differential topology, and in particular, Sard's theorem.   For instance it follows immediately from Sard's theorem that the first condition is satisfied for almost all  $v \in S^2$ since the image of the map $S^1 \rightarrow S^2, s \mapsto \gamma '(s)$ has measure zero.

I have been trying to prove something similar about the set of $v$ which satisfy the second condition but I haven't been successful.  To give an idea for the sorts of tools I was hoping to use I'll explain my attempts.

One idea I had was to consider the map $$f: S^1 \times S^1 - \Delta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (s,t) \mapsto (\gamma '(s) \times \gamma ' (t)) \cdot (\gamma (s) - \gamma (t))$$   where $\Delta$ is the diagonal in the torus, $\times$ is the cross product and $\cdot$ is the dot product. Then $f(s, t) = 0$ iff either {$\gamma (s) - \gamma (t)$ lies in the plane spanned by $\gamma ' (s)$ and $\gamma ' (t)$} or {$\gamma '(s)$ is parallel to $\gamma '(t)$}. In either case, this means $\gamma (s)$ and $\gamma (t)$ must not project to the same point if the projection is to be regular.  This rules out the one dimensional subspace spanned by $\gamma (s) -\gamma (t)$.  Now *if* $0$ were a regular value for $f$ then $f^{-1}(0)$ would be a submanifold of dimension $1$.  We could then consider the smooth map $$f^{-1}(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2, (s,t) \rightarrow [\gamma (s) -\gamma (t)]$$ and apply Sard's theorem to find that almost every $v \in S^2$ also satisfies condition 2.  However, as far as I can tell, there is no good reason $0$ should be a regular value for $f$.  Maybe we could pick an isotope of $\gamma$ with this property? Moreover this still doesn't rule out the possibility that 3 or more points on the curve project to the same point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the chord map
$$\nu\colon S^1\times S^1 - \Delta \to S^2\,, \quad \nu(s,t) = \frac{\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)}{\|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)\|}\,.$$
I'll let you compute that if $\nu(s,t) = v$, then [I think!]
$$d\nu_{(s,t)}(w,z) = \frac1{\|\gamma(s)-\gamma(t)\|}\text{proj}_{T_v S^2}(w-z)\,.$$
So if  $\pm v$ are regular values of $\nu$, you are guaranteed that the projections of $\gamma'(s)$ and $\gamma'(t)$ onto the orthogonal complement of $v$ span.

That there are finitely many points in the preimage of such $[v]\in\mathbb RP^2$ can be argued by making sure that $\pm v$ are never tangent to $\gamma$ and getting a compact $0$-dimensional submanifold of $C\times C - \Delta$.

Comment: Thank you, Ted.  I am probably just confused but wouldn't the first part imply that there exists a projection so that no two distinct points on the curve have parallel derivatives?

Comment: Um, this calculation applies only when the chord for $s$ and $t$ lines up in the direction we're going to project. It doesn't tell us about anything other than $(s,t)\in\nu^{-1}(v)$. Are we ok?

Comment: Ohh ok got it! And the only other tiny detail is that the fibers of intersection points might contain more than two points. But maybe there is a simple remedy

Comment: You can make an independent argument to see that having trisecants is "rare." Take $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$, map by two chords to $S^2\times S^2$, and take the preimage of the diagonal. You then make sure $v$ misses this (at most) curve of directions.

Comment: So you're saying the "two-chords map" is transversal to the diagonal?

Comment: Oh, that's pretty believable actually. Thanks for your help, Ted!  From reading your profile I know this isn't *exactly* your field so you probably don't, but if you happen to know of any books or papers where knot theory foundations are done in this level of detail, please let me know.

Comment: The standard reference is Rolfsen. Do you know it?

Comment: Yeah, I wish he were a bit more detailed though.  He also doesn't usually work in the smooth setting or use much differential topology.